# PHPunit uses 50% more memory in Symfony 2.3.5 than in 2.3.3

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

Today I've updated from Symfony 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 and I noticed that the memory used when running PHPunit has increased a lot.

In 2.3.3: `Time: 06:49, Memory: 92.25Mb`

In 2.3.5: `Time: 06:50, Memory: 134.50Mb`

I'm running my own tests, and I didn't changed anything.

Does someone have an idea about this?

Comment: what component are you testing that takes longer now?

Comment: I just run my own tests, not the tests from symfony.

Comment: Do you test forms, services, commands, controllers or something like that? Do you extend to Symfony2 `WebTestCase`?

Comment: I test Services and Controllers, and yes I extend `WebTestCase`

Comment: You can see the [Changelog for S2 3.4.* here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/CHANGELOG-2.3.md). Scan it for any possible changes that may have affected your *PHPUnit* performance.